# How to load master head content before content head content

Tags: jquery, asp.net, master-pages

I have something like this..

On master Page

```
<head runat="server">
    <link href="../StyleSheets/Main_Master.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <%--<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>--%>
    <script src="../../Scripts/Mainmenu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="../../Misc/Plugins/OrbitSlider/orbit-1.2.3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Misc/Plugins/OrbitSlider/jquery.orbit-1.2.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Content Page

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="LeftBarHeadContent" runat="server">
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <link href="../StyleSheets/Home_Content.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../StyleSheets/Content_Common.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../../Scripts/Contents_Common.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.cycle.all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</asp:Content>
```

Now, this renders on the browser like

```
<head>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
        <link href="../StyleSheets/Home_Content.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="../StyleSheets/Content_Common.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="../../Scripts/Contents_Common.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.cycle.all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link href="../StyleSheets/Main_Master.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <%--<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>--%>
        <script src="../../Scripts/Mainmenu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link href="../../Misc/Plugins/OrbitSlider/orbit-1.2.3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Misc/Plugins/OrbitSlider/jquery.orbit-1.2.3.min.js"></script>
    </head>
```

Now, as you can see that content elements is rendered before the master content. I need the master content to load before as some of my plugins is throwing undifined jquery error if jquery is not included before the plugin appears.

Comment: Where is `LeftBarHeadContent` in your master page? I would expect to see `<asp:contentplaceholder id="LeftBarHeadContent" runat="server" />` in the `<head>` of the master page...

Comment: I got. I have to move the contentplaceholder. Thank you for replying. You comment triggered the thing.

Comment: I've converted it to an answer. Feel free to upvote and mark as correct if you feel it did (or helped to) answer the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where is `LeftBarHeadContent` in your master page?

You need to place something like `<asp:contentplaceholder id="LeftBarHeadContent" runat="server" />` in the `<head>` of the master page...